# how to hide and show a div by clicking other divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need a div to be hide and showed. by default, the div has to be hidden. If anyone click on other specific div/link(but not button), that hidden div will be shown. I want to do it with jQuery. Here is the sample code:

```
<div class="yes"></div> 
<div class="no"></div> 
<p class="notUnderstand"></p>

<div class="proceedContent"></div>
```

Scenario:

1. "proceedContent" div is hidden by default
2. if anyone click on div "yes", "proceedContent" div will be showed
   if "proceedContent" div is hidden
3. if anyone click on div "no" "proceedContent" div will be hidden
   if "proceedContent" div is visible
4. if anyone click on div "notUnderstand" "proceedContent" div will
   be hidden if "proceedContent" div is visible

How can I do it with jQuery?

Comment: I can't write the function with that scenario with onclick function or something like that. I've just select the div $('.a') etc that's it. I can't do jquery well

Comment: how is this not a duplicate of thousands of other questions from SO ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/T4X8n/

you can add click events to any element like shown in fiddle..

```
$('.yes').click(function() {
    $('.proceedContent').show();
});

$('.no, .notUnderstand').click(function() {
    $('.proceedContent').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.yes').click(function() {
    $('.proceedContent').show();
})

$('.no, .notUnderstand').click(function() {
    $('.proceedContent').hide();
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3WuJN/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if ($) {
    $(document).on("click", "#divYes", function ($e) {
      $('#proceedContent).show();
    });
    $(document).on("click", "#divNo", function ($e) {
      $('#proceedContent).hide();
    });
    $(document).on("click", "#notUnderstand", function ($e) {
      $('#proceedContent).hide();
    });
  }
</script>

<div id="divYes"></div> 
<div id="divNo"></div> 

<p id="notUnderstand"></p>

<div id="proceedContent" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **jquery** `not()` selector:

```
$('.yes').click(function() {
    $('.proceedContent').show();
});

$('div').not('.yes').click(function() {
    $('.proceedContent').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for. Using jQuery's `.show()` and `.hide()` this is possible. Here's a link to a fiddle that I created.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/LEUJT/)

Answer (score -1):

This way :

```
$('.yes').click(function() {
    $('.proceedContent').show();
});

$('.no, .notUnderstand').click(function() {
    $('.proceedContent').hide();
});
```